Structure of Multiplication Operator
Consider the operator
$$
M:L^{2}\left[0,1\right] \to L^{2}\left[0,1\right]\quad\mbox{given by}\quad
\operatorname{f} \mapsto 2\cos\left(2\pi x\right)\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)
$$

It follows from the spectral theorem that  $M$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by $x$ on a Hilbert space of the form
$$
\bigoplus_{i = 1}^{\infty}L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}, \mu_{i}\right)
$$
My question is: How could we construct the unitary map $U$ and the measures $\mu_{i}$ in this case ?.
This example is from Reed $\&$ Simon's Classic Functional Analysis text, section ${\tt VII}.2$, example $3$, but they did not provide any additional context on how the construction might look like.
More generally, given some
$\psi \in C^{1}\left(\,\left[\,a,b\,\right]\,\right)$, how do we find the $U,H$ for $M_{\psi}$ ?.

EDIT: This post demonstrate an example where $\psi = x^{2}$, but the construction of $U$ seems a bit unmotivated to me.

Assume $\varphi$ is real valued and  increasing (or decreasing) on $[a,b].$ Denote $\varphi(a)=c$ and $\varphi(b)=d.$ Let $\psi:[c,d]\to[a,b]$ be the inverse function. We have $$\|M_{\varphi}f\|^2=\int\limits_a^b |\varphi(x)|^2|f(x)|^2\,dx $$ On substitution $x=\psi(t)$ we get $$ \|M_{\varphi}f\|^2=\int\limits_c^dt^2|f(\psi(t))|^2\psi'(t)\,dt$$ Denote $d\mu(t)=\psi'(t)\,dt.$ It is natural to define the operator $U:L^2(a,b)\to L^2([c,d],\mu)$ by $$(Uf)(t)=\psi'(t)^{1/2}f(\psi(t))$$ Then $U$ is an isometry and $M=U^{-1}M_tU,$ where $M_t$ is the multiplication operator by $t$ on $L^2([c,d],\mu).$
In the case of decreasing $\varphi$ we switch $c$ with $d$ and $d\mu(t)=-\psi'(t)\,dt$ $$(Uf)(t)=(-\psi'(t))^{1/2}f(\psi(t))$$
In the OP case we have $$L^2(0,1)=L^2(0,1/2)\oplus L^2(1/2,1)$$ On each interval the function $\varphi(x)=2\cos(2\pi x)$ is monotonic.  By applying the above procedure to the intervals we will get two spaces $L^2([-1,1],d\mu_1)$ and $L^2([-1,1],d\mu_2)$ with appropriate $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2.$
Note I have added an answer to   this post
in order to cover the second question there.
